# Get Workbook reference from Open File dialog

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm using an Excel 2013 macro to extract data from a user-selected workbook and my vba is a bit rusty.

`Application.GetOpenFilename` prompts the user for a file location, opens the file and returns a string.  `Workbooks.Open(string)` returns a Workbook - if you know the name in advance.

I want to combine these to ask the user which file to open, and return a Workbook.

Based on Frank's answer here ([Open a workbook using FileDialog and manipulate it in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153342/open-a-workbook-using-filedialog-and-manipulate-it-in-excel-vba)) I've tried this:

```
Function openDataFile() As Workbook
'
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim filename As String
  Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
  fd.Title = "Select the file to extract data"
  'filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(1))
  openDataFile = wb

End Function
```

but this falls over on the commented line with `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.`

How do I prompt the user to open an excel file, and return a reference to it as a workbook?

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Function openDataFile() As Workbook
'
Dim wb            As Workbook
Dim filename      As String
Dim fd            As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
fd.Title = "Select the file to extract data"

' Optional properties: Add filters
fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*" ' show Excel file extensions only

' means success opening the FileDialog
If fd.Show = -1 Then
    filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
End If

' error handling if the user didn't select any file
If filename = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Excel file was selected !", vbExclamation, "Warning"
    End
End If

Set openDataFile = Workbooks.Open(filename)

End Function
```

Then I added the Sub below to test this function:

```
Sub test()

Dim testWb  As Workbook

Set testWb = openDataFile    
Debug.Print testWb.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Sold!  Interestingly, I couldn't do `Workbooks("nameFromFileDialog").Activate` which originally prompted the question.  I was expecting `Workbooks(workbookReference).Activate` to work, but it seems I need `Workbooks(workbookReference.Name).Activate`.  So now I don't get why the string I originally tried doesn't work, but the workbook name string does ... (but i'm not going to lose any sleep over it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't shown the `FileDialog` so maybe something like this:

```
Function openDataFile() As Workbook
'
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim filename As String
  Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
  fd.Title = "Select the file to extract data"
  fd.show
  On Error Resume Next ' handling error over the select.. later in the script you could have an `if fileName = "" then exit sub` or something to that affect
  fileName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
  On Error GoTo 0
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
  openDataFile = wb

End Function
```

Comment: My code does show the FileDialog.  I think the reason for using .show is to see if the filedialog returns true or false.