# VBA - Changing Reference document in named formula

Tags: vba

EDIT: I wanted to clarify my earlier question. I have existing name formula in my name manager. I would like to set these variables listed below to reference different columns from another document. These variables are referenced in my other spreadsheet.

My question is

1) How do I set the variables to reference another document's column?

2) How can I make it so the Macro allows me to choose which document each time?

Here's my code

```
Sub UpdateReport()


Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("U:\user\Destination.xls")


Dim x As Variant
Dim FY123 As Range
Dim FY134 As Range
Dim FY145 As Range
Dim FY156 As Range
Dim FY167 As Range
Dim FINCC As Range



Set FINCC = wbk.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Column("D")
Set FY123 = wbk.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Columns("N")
Set FY134 = wbk.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Columns("O")
Set FY145 = wbk.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Columns("P")
Set FY156 = wbk.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Columns("Q")
Set FY167 = wbk.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Columns("R")

End Sub
```

Thanks,
GS

EDIT: Clarified question

Comment: You need to add the word `Set` to the front of each line where you are trying to set the range variable: `Set FINCC = wbk.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Column("D")`

Comment: ^^ and `Column` would be `Columns`

Comment: I don't know whether my brain hasn't woken up yet this morning, but what do you mean by "the name formulas"?  And does the bit about "allow me to choose which document to reference" mean you want to know how to [Open a workbook using FileDialog and manipulate it in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25153342/6535336)?

Comment: @GrapeSoda  please explain better what you are trying to achieve with your code

Comment: @ShaiRado I have revised the question please help. Thanks!