# VBA Dynamic Save As, Microsoft Project to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I am trying to create a macro that will export a Microsoft Project file into an excel file. Through the use of macro recording I have got a line of code that accomplishes this using the export wizard, but I want the file path and file name to be dynamic so I can use this macro on different projects. I have been searching many other threads and the Microsoft website with no luck. Is this possible?

Here is what I have:

```
   sub formatAndSave ()

   FileSaveAs Name:="C:\Users\XXXXXX\SharePoint\Projects\ProjectType\HxH\myProject.xlsx",_
              FormatID:="MSProject.ACE", map:="myMap"

   end sub
```

One idea I tried was:

```
   Active.Workbook.SaveAs FileName:=Title
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Unless you're talking about [`FileDialog`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25176411/4717755) then what you want is `Dim filePath as String` `filePath = "C:\Users\xxx\..."` and `Dim fileName as String` `fileName = myProject.xlsx"`. Then `FileSaveAs Name:=filePath & fileName`.

Comment: that might work if I can set the fileName to something dynamic, something that recognizes the name of the current file that's open.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume for all answers below your project is located at `c:\projects\myProj.mpp`

I think you're after the string replace function. Something like:

```
Dim excelFilePath As String
excelFilePath = Replace(ActiveProject.FullName, ".mpp", ".xlsx")
Debug.Print excelFilePath
'the output would be c:\projects\myProj.xlsx
```

If you're unfamiliar with string manipulation in VB/VBA, just search the web for "VBA string manipulation". Microsoft has a decent article here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903372(v=vs.71).aspx

A few other things that may be handy for you are these variables:

```
ActiveProject.FullName 'shows full path & name, so you'd get "c:\projects\myProj.mpp"
ActiveProject.Path     'shows just the path, so you'd get "c:\projects\"
ActiveProject.Name     'shows just the file name, so you'd get "myProj.mpp"
```

Finally, one caveat I've seen is that the `ActiveProject.FullName` and `ActiveProject.Name` variables may or may not provide the file extension depending on your local windows environment settings. I've observed that if Windows Explorer is configured to hide file extensions, then these variables also withhold the extension; if Explorer is configured to show them, then they are provided in the variables. Make sure your code is robust to both cases, or make sure you have control over the environment where you code will run.