# Excel VBA Userform Windows Explorer control?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Is there a control that can enable me to put a Windows Explorer widget inside an Excel Userform?

Or at least show objects/icons from a path.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153342/open-a-workbook-using-filedialog-and-manipulate-it-in-excel-vba

Comment: You can try to use `Treeview Control` - paired with `Dir` you can represent directory structure with it as well as show icons.

Comment: hey Robin. the code looks neat. now my only issue how to assign an initial folder in there? i tried looking some things up but .initialfolder property is not showing. any thoughts?

Comment: oh i think i got Robin. .initialfile worked. too bad i can't pick your post as answer but thanks.