# input box for opening file works only with short names

Tags: excel, vba

I've some problems with my code as it has to open a closed excel file , it works only if the name is short , as the file come automatically out as "OPEN ORDERS 16.05.2018" I'd like to be able to input this without having the rename the file OPEN_ORDER  for example as this works with the last one but not the long name.

```
Sub OOR()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
Dim xWb As Workbook

ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\[" & mnt & ".xlsx]Sheet 1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("\\data\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ty = Array("=INDEX(" & mnt & "!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=" & mnt & "!$E:$E)*(J2=" & mnt & "!$J:$J),0))")
ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
xWb.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
=INDEX(OPEN ORDERS '[16.07.2018]16.07'!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E5=OPEN ORDERS '[16.07.2018]16.07'!$E:$E)*(J5=OPEN ORDERS '[16.07.2018]16.07'!$J:$J),0))
```

This is the formula that comes out once the name typed in , and i don't know why it opens `OPEN ORDERS '[16.07.2018]16.07` when prompted OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018 there's probably a problem with the space and the "." but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: It is not the length that is the problem. It are the `.`'s in the filename.

Comment: @Basho: so where in your code is it failing? Have you tried [F8 Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)?

Comment: @Basho: please see this [related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153342/open-a-workbook-using-filedialog-and-manipulate-it-in-excel-vba) where you will find some help

Comment: `Workbooks.Open("\\data\Documents\" & mnt` -you need the complete folder address

Comment: @Basho: You're error might be `mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\[" & mnt & ".xlsx]Sheet 1'" ` - are you **sure the sheet name is `Sheet 1`** and not *`Sheet1`*?

Comment: @Davesexcel The folder adress is fine i just hid a part of it to hide the companies name etc , the folder adress is not the problem neither  the sheet as like written in the question if i just change the name from the excel to OPEN_ORDER instead of the natural name OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018 It works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Basho: Put a breakpoint (F9) on the line `ty = Array("=INDEX(" & mnt & "!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=" & mnt & "!$E:$E)*(J2="` ... and run the macro, when it stops on that line you can check the value of `mnt` in the Immediate Window (CTRL+G) then `?mnt`

Comment: Ok i'm dumb the problem was that i still have mnt in the ty = while i shouldv' put mnt2

Comment: @OurManinBananas but thanks the breakpoint made me realize it wasn't the right variable inside the formula and i didn't knew about breakpoints before !

Comment: @Basho: see [F8 Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) and [Ozgrid: Debugging Excel VBA](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/debug.htm)

Comment: @Basho: your question is very likely to be closed as Off Topic ... (simple Typographical/spelling error close reason)

Comment: @OurManinBananas I flagged it as such yes

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub OOR()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim mnt As String, mnt2 As String
Dim xWb As Workbook

ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
mnt = InputBox("Filename")
mnt2 = "'H:\Documents\[" & mnt & ".xlsx]Sheet 1'" ' Change Sheet1 to the actual tabname
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("\\data\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ty = Array("=INDEX(" & mnt2 & "!$R:$R,MATCH(1,(E2=" & mnt2 & "!$E:$E)*(J2=" & mnt2 & "!$J:$J),0))")
ws.Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaArray = ty
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
xWb.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```