# Can I assign a string value containing the name of a workbook as an argument?

Tags: excel, vba

To summarize, the workbook's name changes twice every week and me instead of thinking of another optmized way to do it automatically, decided to simply show an inputbox where the current workbook's name will be typed in and then assign it to:

```
Public fileName As String
fileName = InputBox("Type here the current workbook's name: ")
```

---

```
Dim ext As String
ext = ".xlsb"

Set wk = Excel.Workbooks(fileName & ext)
```

> Error 9: subscript out of range

Comment: is the workbook you're looking for already open? If not then you'll get that error (and would instead need to use the Workbooks.Open method).  If it is already open, then a typo from manually entering the workbook name is the most likely culprit.  Generally you should avoid that entirely though and I'd recommend showing the Open File dialog so that the user can select the file they're interested in, much less room for error that way.  Even better, if you can predict the name of the workbook (because it changes in a known fashion), it would be best to generate/calculate the name.

Comment: It wasn't open actually I feel stupid now and thanks for the suggestion. I've been using macros for less than a month so there's a lot to learn yet.

Comment: Is the workbook you're trying to work with the one containing the code?  If that's the case you can just do `Set wk=ThisWorkbook` and avoid the need for a name altogether.

Comment: And if you need to open the worksheet, consider using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` instead of asking the user to type in a file name (which they will inevitably get wrong half the time)

Comment: @DavidN it isn't unfortunately

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Alright, I'll definetely use it. Do you by any chance know how can I manipulate the values of a closed Workbook?

Comment: This begs the question, why not use `FileDialog` instead? It's much more foolproof than to let users type away at file names

Comment: I agree with you, just leaned about this function about 1h ago.

Comment: Here is an example with [File Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154160/8309643). If you need to manipulate values in a closed workbook you'll, unfortunately, have to open it. Turning off screen updating will help performance some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Technically this is not exactly, what you were asking for, but it is a much better programming practice to let users select files within
>   the OS interface, rather than to let them type-away at file names,
>   which ultimately arrives at the same goal.*

I've created a custom function for picking files via the `FileDialog` object. As an optional argument, you can enforce a specific file-type in the `format` argument.

### `get_file([format], [fullpath])`

```
' Returns a file name of a selected file via the .FileDialog object
' Arguments:
'    [format] : Optional argument, if left empty any file format can be selected, _
                otherwise enforce what [format] was put in to be selected
'    [fullpath] : Optional argument, if left empty will only return FileName.xxx, _
                  otherwise will return full path (eg. D:\MyDir\Book.xlsx")
' Returns: A <String> with the selected filename.
```

This is how the function looks like:

```
Private Function get_file(Optional ByVal format As String = "nomatch", _
                          Optional ByVal fullpath As Boolean = False) As String

    Dim fs As FileDialog: Set fs = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim goodmatch As Boolean: goodmatch = False

    Do Until goodmatch = True
        With fs
            If .Show <> -1 Then
                .Title = "Choose a Workbook to work with"
                .AllowMultiSelect = False
                .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
            End If

            If format = "nomatch" Then
                goodmatch = True
            Else
                format = Replace(format, ".", "")
                If Mid(.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(.SelectedItems(1), ".") + 1) <> format Then
                    MsgBox "Please select a " & format & " file format", vbCritical
                Else
                    goodmatch = True
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Loop

    If fullpath = True Then
       get_file = fs.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
       get_file = Mid(fs.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(fs.SelectedItems(1), "\") + 1)
    End If

End Function
```

Example user of the function:

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(get_file(".xlsx", fullpath:= True))
    ' saves a workbook of only .xlsx type from what user selected into wb variable
    Debug.Print wb.Name
End Sub
```

Opened the workbook with the `[fullpath]` for proper link (`True`)  wit the enforced `.xlsx` `[format]` and printed the `Name` propert of the `Workbook` object saved inside the `wb` variable

[image]