# How to replace file path in Excel VBA code to be File dialog "File picker"

Tags: excel

please advise how to edit the below code be get the File picker dialog works in the below code:

```
Sub Update_Riyadh_Store()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog


Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = Sheets("Riyadh Stock").Range("A1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'sheets and range to be updated'

Sheets("Riyadh Stock").Select
Range("A1:F2500").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Riyadh Stock").Range("A31").Select
ٍSet FileToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Exit Sub
Else
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
With Sheet.UsedRange
.Copy PasteStart
Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
End With
Next Sheet 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
wb2.Close 
MsgBox "Stock has been updated successfully.", vbOKOnly, "Updated Successfully"
End Sub
```

Please advise what is missing to make this code works.

Comment: tried what? i am already using the above code and i tried to replace it with the filerpicker code that is everywhere but i could not manage to make it work.

Comment: i added the below: Dim FolderToOpen As Office.FileDialog
Set FolderToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) , instead of the one in the above code, and tried many ways to edit rest of the relevant parts of the code to make it work with no luck, i am not a programmer just trying to search. thanks

Comment: Done, hope it is more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Unlikely, i tried to edit my code using the one you proposed but i could not get it work, i know it is my weak experience in coding though, thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry wrong one (I misread and thought it was folder picker). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153342/open-a-workbook-using-filedialog-and-manipulate-it-in-excel-vba).